# Diagramming tool for WPF

Tags: diagramming

I wish to create a diagram similar to VS.NET class diagram.

I have seen Sukram's article on codeproject.com, called DiagramDesigner. But I have found this solution a little difficult to implement, I want the control with + and - buttons for expanding and collapsing.

Are there any vendors of a custom control similar to VS.NET Class diagram designer. Any ready solutions available?

Click of + the child nodes should expand. Click of - these nodes should minimize.

I have also seen Sacha Barber's spider tree control. But this too does not suit my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into VS built in diagramming engine. You would be able to create your own [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) to define how you want your diagram to look and interact. You would then use VS's built in code gereration tools to generate the code and XAML you want.

Check out [this webcast](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/AnthonyC/Advanced-code-generation-patterns-with-T4--DSL-Tools/) if you want to see a demonstration.